# ESP32-H2 low-level radio access

Tags: esp32, radio-transmission

here's a portion of the block-diagram for the ESP32-H2:

[image]

question: is there "register-level" access to the **RF** block??? can i implement a customized 2.4 GHz protocol on this device???

at some level, there is presumably a generic FSK transceiver that supports both BLE and 802.15.4...  is this accessible to bare-metal firmware; and if so, where can i find additional documentation???

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The low level radio drivers on all ESP32 CPUs are provided only as closed-source binary blobs which are linked into applications. The data sheets provide no insights into how to talk to the radio subsystems other than the fact that ADC2 is used in ESP32 and ESP32-S2/S3 CPUs.

You can find the binary blobs in the [esp32-phy-lib](https://github.com/espressif/esp-phy-lib) module which is a component of ESP-IDF.

Comment: i'm looking at some of the include/ and src/ files associated with this component, but can i realistically use this in a "standalone" manner to implement my own upper-layers atop this PHY????  said another way, is this component **only** used by the BLE and 802.15.4 stacks and is really an internal artifact????

Comment: If you're someone who has the level of skills to reverse engineer them and understand what's going on with them, then it's possible you might be able to. There are very few people out there with that level of skill. Which is the reason that if you search for projects that have done this you'll find maybe one, which doesn't share the details. They are entirely undocumented, unsupported, and not meant for the kind of use you're talking about. So the answer is almost certainly "no you will not succeed at this".